# Automated tests for JavaScript application using TFS

Tags: javascript, testing, tfs, coded-ui-tests

Is it possible to create automated tests for a JS app using Visual Studio and Team Foundation Server? I have found out how to create (record) simple tests. But the problem is my app's controls aren't being recognized correctly. There are so many warnings while recording that I can't generate Coded UI Tests from them (most of them while mouse hovering/clicking on something - e.g. simple hyperlink).

**[edit]**
[image: error]

Comment: Please explain or show some of the warnings you are getting. Coded UI should work OK with JavaScript.

Comment: While recording a step in Testing Center, please check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with early versions of Visual Studio 2012. Other forums suggest that installing, or sometimes reinstalling, Visual Studio 2012 update 2 fixes the issue. See for example http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/89fc2be6-0229-4c07-86dc-5ce093c5b248/error-in-aggregating-action-in-actionfilter-webdialogaggregator-detailed-errormtm-fails-to-apply and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b945c9a3-a72e-4ed8-b8c5-74be3f264af1/error-at-recording-winform-application and http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783750/mtm-fails-to-apply-intent-aware-action-recording-and-throws-an-exception#details